# Matrix multiplication is not commutative. What is the work around or solution?

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, rotation

I basically have this problem:

[Generic Simple 3D Matrix Rotation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409197/generic-simple-3d-matrix-rotation-issue)

and it is driving me mad. I have been on Google for hours but cannot find any posts about solving the problem mathematically. How do I successfully rotate an object around 3 axis with a matrix and avoid this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: If you really have this exact problem, then this question is an exact duplicate and should not even exist. If your problem is slightly different, you should explain it in detail, not just link to another question which already has an answer.

Comment: This is not a programming failure; it's a lack of understanding of matricies and geometry.

Comment: I have asked the question again as the previous question did not provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I have found the answer here:

http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/rotation/

The solution is: "One easy way to work around this problem is to keep a second matrix around that will store all of the accumulated rotations." :-)

Comment: if this is the solution you should check it so the question is marked as answered. Just click on the check under vote score on the top left of the answer. (does not matter if it is yours)

Answer (score 1):

The solution/workaraound is to apply the rotations in the correct order.

If you have rotation matrices A, B and C and want to apply them to matrix M in order A, B, C then the solution is:

First apply A:

```
A * M
```

Then B:

```
B * A * M
```

And finally C:

```
C * B * A * M
```

If you want to apply ABC frequently you can precalculate the combined rotation matrix R:

```
R = C * B * A
```

and then you can apply R to M:

```
R * M
```

Comment: Maybe I have some misunderstanding of the concepts involved. Thank you for this answer so far. Why would I want to apply them in an order? What is the 'correct order'? With my object, rotating around x 90, then y 90 results in a rotation of 90 around z, which is not what I want or expected!?

Comment: @user3725725 The order you choose depends on your requirements. *You* need to figure out which transformation you to apply first to your model, which one second, and so on. If you are treating your vectors as column vectors then the rightmost one is applied first. If you are treating your vectors as row vectors, then the left-most matrix is applied first.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to rotate direct object transform matrix around its own axises.

- in that case it is really simple (but I also spend much time solving this years back)
- `M0` is original object matrix
- `R` is transformation you want to apply (rotation)
- `M1` is the result new object matrix
- `M1 = Inverse(Inverse(M0)*R)`

That is all. you just have to add 4x4 inverse matrix routine to your code for example here is mine

```
void  matrix_subdet    (double *c,double *a)
        {
        double   q[16];
        int     i,j;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (j=0;j<4;j++)
          q[j+(i<<2)]=matrix_subdet(a,i,j);
        for (i=0;i<16;i++) c[i]=q[i];
        }
double matrix_subdet    (         double *a,int r,int s)
        {
        double   c,q[9];
        int     i,j,k;
        k=0;                            // q = sub matrix
        for (j=0;j<4;j++)
         if (j!=s)
          for (i=0;i<4;i++)
           if (i!=r)
                {
                q[k]=a[i+(j<<2)];
                k++;
                }
        c=0;
        c+=q[0]*q[4]*q[8];
        c+=q[1]*q[5]*q[6];
        c+=q[2]*q[3]*q[7];
        c-=q[0]*q[5]*q[7];
        c-=q[1]*q[3]*q[8];
        c-=q[2]*q[4]*q[6];
        if (int((r+s)&1)) c=-c;       // add signum
        return c;
        }
double matrix_det       (         double *a)
        {
        double c=0;
        c+=a[ 0]*matrix_subdet(a,0,0);
        c+=a[ 4]*matrix_subdet(a,0,1);
        c+=a[ 8]*matrix_subdet(a,0,2);
        c+=a[12]*matrix_subdet(a,0,3);
        return c;
        }
double matrix_det       (         double *a,double *b)
        {
        double c=0;
        c+=a[ 0]*b[ 0];
        c+=a[ 4]*b[ 1];
        c+=a[ 8]*b[ 2];
        c+=a[12]*b[ 3];
        return c;
        }
void  matrix_inv       (double *c,double *a)
        {
        double   d[16],D;
        matrix_subdet(d,a);
        D=matrix_det(a,d);
        if (D) D=1.0/D;
        for (int i=0;i<16;i++) c[i]=d[i]*D;
        }
```

- hope I did not forget to copy something
- usage is     `matrix_inv(dst,src)`
- returns inverse matrix of `src` to `dst`
- both `src` and `dst` are `double[16]` linear arrays representing 4x4 transform matrix

[Edit1] 3x3 matrix

Mine matrix layout is this (OpenGL like):

```
double M[16];
a00 a04 a08 a12
a01 a05 a09 a13
a02 a06 a10 a14
a03 a07 a11 a15
```

- where `a??` is ??-th value from `M[]`

Now if you want to use 4x4 inverse of 3x3 matrix just do this

```
double m[9];
b00 b03 b06 0
b01 b04 b07 0
b02 b05 b08 0
0   0   0   1
```

- where `b??` is ??-th value from your 3x3 `m[]`
- so load 4x4 matrix this way
- invert
- and extract 3x3 matrix back
- You can always rewrite mine 4x4 inverse to 3x3 (I am too lazy to do that)
- but it will get very simplified because determinant and sub-determinants will get very simple

just to be sure you get it right m[3*3] -> M[4*4] will be like this:

```
M[ 0]=m[0];
M[ 1]=m[1];
M[ 2]=m[2];
M[ 3]=0.0;
M[ 4]=m[3];
M[ 5]=m[4];
M[ 6]=m[5];
M[ 7]=0.0;
M[ 8]=m[6];
M[ 9]=m[7];
M[10]=m[8];
M[11]=0.0;
M[12]=0.0;
M[13]=0.0;
M[14]=0.0;
M[15]=1.0;
```

And backwards m[3*3] <- M[4*4] will be like this:

```
m[0]=M[ 0];
m[1]=M[ 1];
m[2]=M[ 2];
m[3]=M[ 4];
m[4]=M[ 5];
m[5]=M[ 6];
m[6]=M[ 8];
m[7]=M[ 9];
m[8]=M[10];
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very helpful. My matrix is a 3x3 float[] array in Java. So now I'm stuck again :(

Comment: @user3725725 added [edit1] to answer (how to use it on 3x3 matrices) btw there are most certainly some 3x3 inverse matrix C++ source code out there just look for it (mine is via Cramer's rule) or rewrite mine to 3x3 it should be quite easy. (I am sure I have it somewhere but too lazy to dig it up from 10+ years old source code backups). btw you use 3x3 matrices for 2D or 3D transforms?

Comment: @user3725725 also change all the `double`s to `float`s to match your data types