# Convert a bounding box in ECEF coordinates to ENU coordinates

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, coordinate-systems

I have a geometry with its vertices in cartesian coordinates. These cartesian coordinates are the ECEF(Earth centred earth fixed) coordinates. This geometry is actually present on an ellipsoidal model of the earth using wgs84 corrdinates.The cartesian coordinates were actually obtained by converting the set of latitudes and longitudes along which the geomtries lie but i no longer have access to them. What i have is an axis aligned bounding box with xmax, ymax, zmax and xmin,ymin,zmin obtained by parsing the cartesian coordinates (There is no obviously no cartesian point of the geometry at xmax,ymax,zmax or xmin,ymin,zmin. The bounding box is just a cuboid enclosing the geometry).

What i want to do is to calculate the camera distance in an overview mode such that this geometry's bounding box  perfectly fits the camera frustum.

I am not very clear with the approach to take here. A method like using a local to world matrix comes to mind but its not very clear.[image]

@Specktre I referred to your suggestions on shifting points in 3D and that led me to another improved solution, nevertheless not perfect.

1. Compute a matrix that can transfer from ECEF to ENU. Refer this - http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Transformations_between_ECEF_and_ENU_coordinates
2. Rotate all eight corners of my original bounding box using this matrix.
3. Compute a new bounding box by finding the min and max of x,y,z of these rotated points
4. compute distance

   - `cameraDistance1 = ((newbb.ymax - newbb.ymin)/2)/tan(fov/2)`
   - `cameraDistance2 = ((newbb.xmax - newbb.xmin)/2)/(tan(fov/2)xaspectRatio)`
   - `cameraDistance = max(cameraDistance1, cameraDistance2)`

This time i had to use the aspect ratio along x as i had previously expected since in my application fov is along y. Although this works almost accurately, there is still a small bug i guess. I am not very sure if it a good idea to generate a new bounding box. May be it is more accurate to identify 2 points point1(xmax, ymin, zmax) and point(xmax, ymax, zmax) in the original bounding box, find their values after multiplying with matrix and then do (point2 - point1).length(). Similarly for y. Would that be more accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **transform matrix**

   first thing is to understand that [transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) represents coordinate system. Look here [Transform matrix anatomy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216549/2521214) for another example.

   In standard **OpenGL** notation If you use **direct matrix** then you are converting from matrix local space (**LCS**) to world global space (**GCS**). If you use **inverse matrix** then you converting coordinates from **GCS** to **LCS**
2. **camera matrix**

   camera matrix converts to camera space so you need the inverse matrix. You get camera matrix like this:

   ```
   camera=inverse(camera_space_matrix)
   ```

   now for info on how to construct your `camera_space_matrix` so it fits the bounding box look here:

   - [Frustrum distance computation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22038740/2521214)

   so compute `midpoint` of the top rectangle of your box compute camera `distance` as max of distance computed from all vertexes of box so

   ```
   camera position = midpoint + distance*midpoint_normal
   ```

   orientation depends on your projection matrix. If you use `gluPerspective` then you are viewing -Z or +Z according selected `glDepthFunc`. So set Z axis of matrix to normal and `Y,X` vectors can be aligned to North/South and East/West so for example

   ```
   Y=Z x (1,0,0)
   X = Z x Y
   ```

   now put position, and axis vectors `X,Y,Z` inside matrix, compute inverse matrix and that it is.

[image: camera space]

**[Notes]**

Do not forget that **FOV** can have different angles for X and Y axis (aspect ratio).

Normal is just `midpoint` - Earth center which is (0,0,0) so normal is also the midpoint. Just normalize it to size `1.0`.

For all computations use cartesian world **GCS** (global coordinate system).

Comment: So from what i understand - 1) I compute a world to local matrix - to transform my coordinates to the local space 2) I shift all 8 points of my axis aligned bounding box using this matrix so that now they have the values in my object space. From here it is not clear to me - What i think is i would need something like ((boundingBox.someCorner - boundingBox.someOtherCorner)/2)/tan(fovy/2).  Would these corners be  - (bb.xmin, bb.ymin, bb.zmax) and (bb.xmin, bb.ymax, bb.zmax) in world coordinates?

Comment: @user1783299 yes all corners are in GCS. just compute the middle (average) point of the plane closer to camera (it is bigger rectangle in view), then compute normal from this point (you will need it to construct camera space matrix) then compute the distance from mid point so the view fits your rectangle as you wish. and last compute camera space axises vectors X,Y,Z and origin (all in GCS)... put it together to matrix, compute inverse of it and that it is what you need (just multiply this inverted matrix on top of your model-view matrix)

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25176378/2521214 is mine C++ inverse matrix computation which I use for 4x4 OpenGL transform matrices

Comment: Please check my edit on the post. The currently working (may fail, i am afraid) solution doesnt seem to be right !!

Comment: @raveesh that depends on the projection matrix used. for example `gluPerspective` has the screen X-axis constant and Y axis is adapting to match aspect ratio. so no matter the aspect ratio X is the same and Y is changing. Try to resize your window and you will see that along x axis is the view the same (can (un)zoom with screen X-size change but you will see the same chunk of world space all the time) along the y axis the view will changing on any change of aspect ratio or x or y screen size.

Comment: I have again provided an improved version of the solution although it doesnt seem accurate

Comment: @raveesh what is wrong with your solution now? if you combine big and small numbers then floats are sometimes not enough. (if the view jumps ... is jittery and the amplitude is rising with distance then it is floating error) in that case use double if you can. if aspect ratio does not fit then sometimes you need to check which axis is bigger and use 2 different aspect equations one if XS>=YS and the other if XS<YS.