# 3D orthographic projection with rotating camera

Tags: python, math, numpy, geometry, projection

I'm currently trying to orthographically project a 3 dimensional point (p - 3-D vector in homogeneous coordinates) onto a 2 dimensional camera plane (q - 2-D vector in homogeneous coordinates).

To achieve this i build up this **projection matrix**:

[image]

- `D` is the extrinsic matrix for camera rotation `R` and translation `t`
- `K` is the intrinsic matrix composed from `cx` and `cy` for offset of origns
- `kx` and `ky` for scaling and `Theta` is the skew between the axis.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**edit 1**: Obviously it is correct the way described here. The 3D to 2D projection actually works as described in my question. There have been some errors in my implementation, that leaded to some errors. My question was completely nonsense. I will mark this post as deleted.

**edit 2**: Thanks for embedding the pictures, i could'd do it myself (lack of privileges/points in this forum). This was the reason why i posted the picture links as source code...

**edit 3**: Source of this world-camera-projection method is: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/lecture13.pdf

Comment: 1. for html links use html link tool (that earth icon on the left in edit tools) when you pass it as code it is not translated as link and so not usable directly ... 2. for those of us with bad abstract imagination you should add images of how your projection looks like so we can have an idea of it (not everyone is experienced in tomography) respective what you want to achieve

Comment: for example something like image on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419671/2521214 answer. it should have all the input variables you want (angles,distances ...)